# Running a query with variables via QueryTables

Tags: sql, excel, vba, variables, odbc

I created a basic Sub to run a query and return the results in the active Worksheet in Cell A1.

```vb
Sub MySub()
'Assemble the connection string
 strDSN = "MyDSN"
 strPass = "MyPass"
 strUsername = "MyUser"
 strConnection = "ODBC;DSN=" & strDSN & ";UID=" & strUsername & ";PWD=" & strPass
 strQuery = "MyQuery"

 With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=strConnection, Destination:=Cells(1, 1))
        .CommandText = strQuery
        .FieldNames = True
        .RefreshStyle = 0
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
 End With
End Sub
```

This sub works fine with queries like:
`Select distinct TOP 3 Time FROM [WBServiceLogs]`

The sub fails if I declare a variable in the SQL like e.g.:
`Declare @Shift INT SET @Shift = 100 Select distinct TOP 3 Time + @Shift FROM [WBServiceLogs]`

I get an error: `Application-defined or object-defined error`

The query itself is OK, it runs fine in SQL Server Mgt Studio. Or via ODBC in e.g. WinSQL.

Any suggestions?  Thanks!